# Paypal Chained Payments shipping address

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I use Adaptive Chained Payments for my app(buyer send money, I get my % fee and than send the rest to seller). I follow the next logic:

```
-On actionType: CREATE and paymentType: SERVICE
-call PAY api, 
-receive payKey, 
-setPaymentOption(where I set the shipping address)
-redirect to paypal page to pay(on review page I can see shipping address)
-login in seller page and I have this message: Seller Protection Not Eligible(We have no shipping address on file.)
```

And on SetPaymentOptions:

```
 setPaymentsOption($payKey){
    $header = array(
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: {$this->user}",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: {$this->password}",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: {$this->signature}",
    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: {$this->app_id}",
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV",
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV"
    );
    $data = array(
    'payKey' => $payKey,
    'requestEnvelope.errorLanguage'=>'en_US',
    'senderOptions.requireShippingAddressSelection'=>'true',
    'senderOptions.addressOverride'=>'true',
    'senderOptions.shippingAddress.addresseeName'=> 'John',
    'senderOptions.shippingAddress.city'=>'San+Jose',
    'senderOptions.shippingAddress.country'=>'US',
    'senderOptions.shippingAddress.phone.countryCode' => '91',
    'senderOptions.shippingAddress.phone.phoneNumber' =>'408123456',
    'senderOptions.shippingAddress.phone.type' =>'MOBILE',
    'senderOptions.shippingAddress.state' =>'CA',
    'senderOptions.shippingAddress.street1' =>'17+Magneson+St',
    'senderOptions.shippingAddress.street2' =>'building+1',
    'senderOptions.shippingAddress.zip' => '12345',
    );

    URL : https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/SetPaymentOptions/ $data/$header
    }

    Result : 
           [responseEnvelope.timestamp] => 2014-04-03T04:23:14.827-07:00
           [responseEnvelope.ack] => Success
           [responseEnvelope.correlationId] => 1037e10d7e4da
          [responseEnvelope.build] => 10273932
```

I'm not getting any error message.Everything works fine, I make the payment(on Review your information I have Shipping Address) but on transaction details I still get Seller Protection Not Eligible

So what I am doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Please be more specific. Can you tell the exact error you're getting? For example, what did you try and what errors did you get?

Comment: Well this is the problem, I'm not getting any error message.Everything works fine, I make the payment(on Review your information I have Shipping Address) but on transaction details I still get Seller Protection Not Eligible

Comment: Can you update this on the question? It will also help to add *real* code snippets (without sensitive information).

Comment: Should I also set GetPaymentOptions?